# While running angularJS test file test cases failed: Chrome 35.0.1916 titleCrtl Intially has a title FAILED

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, windows-7

When I execute this command: karma start karma.conf.js, I get the below mentioned error:

Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7) titleCrtl Intially has a title FAILED Error [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myModule due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

And this is my test.js file:

```
describe('titleCrtl', function()
{
    var controller = null;
    var $scope = null;

    beforeEach(function()
    {
        module('myModule');
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope)
    {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('titleCrtl',
        {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    }));
    it('Intially has a title', function()
    {
        assert.equal($scope.title,"Hello!");
    });
    it('Clicking the button changes the title', function()
    {
        $scope.changeIt();
        assert.equal($scope.title,"World!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this:

Just instantiate the module in javascript file like:

var myModule = angular.module('app',[]); and then define a controller.